# How are these integrals equal?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, equivalence-relations, cauchy-integral-formula

I am struggling to understand how the highlighted two integrals are equal to each other. I changed $\sin(2bx)$ into exponential form to help, but it doesn't seem to be helping at all. Also $b$ is just a number greater than $>0$.

[image]

Comment: We can't write a complex analysis course for you. You need to read one : holomorphic and analytic functions, contour integrals, Cauchy integral theorem and formula, residue theorem, analytic continuation.

Comment: @reuns if you can stop being mean that would be helpful. You do not know my position and wellbeing.

Comment: Very funny. Do you want some help ?

Comment: @reuns  I am never going to ask a question again thanks for the put down, didn't realise I was annoying people. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: In your first question I showed you the simplest example you need to work on : $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{2i \pi \xi x}}{2 i \pi \xi +|a|}d\xi = e^{-|a| x} 1_{x > 0}$ where $f(z) = \frac{e^{2 i\pi z x}}{2i\pi z+|a|}$ has only one pole at $z = -|a|/2i \pi$

Answer (score 1):

It comes from equating/comparing the real and imaginary parts (the imaginary part being 0) of the previous line.  Not sure where that line comes from though...

The imaginary parts must cancel, giving
$$
e^{b^2} \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \sin 2bx \ dx = \int_0^b e^{y^2} \ dy.
$$
Now shuffle the $e^{b^2}$ over to the other side by dividing it, giving the negated exponent.